# GM Script: Revert changes to Unanswered Questions Box

Tags: script, style, greasemonkey

If you are like me and think that the new styling for unanswered question *drastically hurts* the site's usability, rejoice.

I've created a Greasemonkey script which will return unanswered questions to their old glory.

**Download:** [Stack Overflow Old Unanswered Boxes](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/99214)
**Compatible:** Chrome / Firefox

[image: Ahh, like it should be! Now grab a beer!]

Discussion about this change is available at [Eeeek! Why is StackOverflow naked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83600/eeeek-why-is-stackoverflow-naked)

Comment: No way! SO **has** to respond to the community and get those old colors back!

Comment: Also this is not a use case for userscripts. A simple user.css does the trick.

Comment: @mario: A simple user.css is hard to install in Chrome.

Comment: True, it's significantly more involving in Chrome than in Firefox or Opera. Needs an extension first. Though it does work with most builds of [chromium-browser  --enable-user-stylesheet](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2393) by using `~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Content.css`

Comment: Don't how it comes, as long it works and fixes the stupid change.

Comment: Would be nice if you added the vote box back in as well (http://i.imgur.com/LEsfj.png)